# Get time data from DB - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to give an alert when a condition is met in a day time, right now I get the hours statically

> $hour1 = strtotime ("09:00");
>         $hour2 = strtotime ("01:00");

**but I want to get the established schedule from the DB**

[image]

```
 $hour1 = strtotime ("09:00");
  $hour2 = strtotime ("01:00");
  if ($hour1 > $hour2) {
     Session::flash('message', 'ABIERTO!'); 
     Session::flash('', ''); 
  }
  elseif ($hour1 < $hour2 ) {
     Session::flash('message', 'SHOP CLOSED!'); 
     Session::flash('alert-class', 'alert-danger'); 
    }
```

I already created the model on table status

help pls

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
$hour1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $status->open);
$hour2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $status->closed);
```

**OR** just simply

```
$hour1 = new DateTime($status->open);
$hour2 = new DateTime($status->closed);
```

Then just make conditional

```
if ($hour1 > $hour2)
    // what to do
```

Comment: error: Property [open] does not exist on this collection instance.  code; https://pastebin.com/EdF4hARn

Comment: your query seems like resulting in Collection, you need to iterate using `foreach` or `for` after that you can do the code above inside it.

Comment: you need to query like this `$status = Status::first();` in case you want only get single record